# ui-router minification of templateUrl?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this code:

```
.config(
['$locationProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider', '$sceProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($locationProvider, $sceDelegateProvider, $sceProvider, $stateProvider) {

    var access = {
        name: 'access',
        url: '/Access/:content',
        templateUrl: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
            var x = $stateParams;
            var page = 'app/access/partials/' + $stateParams.content + '.html';
            return page;
        }]
    };
```

I did what I thought was needed to make this work when minified but it seems like AngularJS is unable to resolve `$stateParams`.

Has anyone come across a similar problem?

Comment: Can you paste your HTML snippet and js code snippet where you have configured the ui-router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`templateUrl` property accepts a string or a function, and the function only accepts a single parameter, which is `toParams` - it does not support injectable parameters.

In your case, assign the function directly without the array:

```
.state("access", {
   // ...
   templateUrl: function(toParams){
      var page = 'app/access/partials/' + toParams.content + '.html';
      return page;
   }
});
```

Comment: For posterity's sake, this answer is not correct.  templateUrl is not an injected function.  It is always called with a single parameter, which is the `toParams`.  There is no need to annotate or use array notation.

Comment: @ChrisT, is this the case with newer versions? Because I tested the example above in 0.2.14

Comment: Yes, it's still the case. Your example will work even if you remove the $inject annotation